# Moria's goblins

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

Why were the goblins in the Mines of Moria so silent that they could all suddenly hear the noise of the bucket dropping down the well and KNOW it wasn't one of them (and its location)? Do they hibernate or something?

Answer (score 23):

First, the movie plays a bit different to the book in that Pippin purposefully drops a stone down the well, and because the characters hear the "plop" they fall silent and become aware of a faint "tom-tap". There's quite a bit of time between this event and the goblins finally appearing, so there isn't necessarily a cause and effect here.

As for the movie events - it could be that the goblins were already aware that western gate had been opened and the fellowship were in the mines, but didn't have sufficient numbers and/or didn't know precisely where they were. The noise of the bucket and armour falling would have alerted them to exactly where the fellowship had got themselves.

The movie compresses time considerably - it appears that they are only the mines for a few hours in the movie, whereas it is several days in the book.